# autofilling from preselect options that works with adding new lines

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I need to be able to autopopulate form fields while keeping ability to add new lines:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="invoiceItem">   
                    <tr>
                        <th width="2%"><input id="checkAll" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox"></th>
                        <th width="15%">Item No</th>
                        <th width="38%">Item Name</th>
                        <th width="15%">Quantity</th>
                        <th width="15%">Price</th>                              
                        <th width="15%">Total</th>
                    </tr>                           
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="itemRow" type="checkbox"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="productCode[]" id="productCode_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="productName[]" id="productName_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>            
                        <td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control quantity" autocomplete="off"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_1" class="form-control price" autocomplete="off"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total_1" class="form-control total" autocomplete="off"></td>
                    </tr>                       
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" id="removeRows" type="button">- Delete</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" id="addRows" type="button">+ Add More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and my JS to add new lines is here:

```
var count = $(".itemRow").length;
$(document).on('click', '#addRows', function() { 
    count++;
    var htmlRows = '';
    htmlRows += '<tr>';
    htmlRows += '<td><input class="itemRow" type="checkbox"></td>';          
    htmlRows += '<td><input type="text" name="productCode[]" id="productCode_'+count+'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>';          
    htmlRows += '<td><input type="text" name="productName[]" id="productName_'+count+'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>'; 
    htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_'+count+'" class="form-control quantity" autocomplete="off"></td>';        
    htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_'+count+'" class="form-control price" autocomplete="off"></td>';      
    htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total_'+count+'" class="form-control total" autocomplete="off"></td>';          
    htmlRows += '</tr>';
    $('#invoiceItem').append(htmlRows);
}); 
$(document).on('click', '#removeRows', function(){
    $(".itemRow:checked").each(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
    $('#checkAll').prop('checked', false);
    calculateTotal();
});
```

and this works great, as long as i dont want to autopopulate row (item id, name and price) using single

I know there should be a simple solution but i am staring in a blank